# Prove whether this is true or false: For every two sets $A$ and $B$, $\{A\oplus B, A\cap B\}$ is a partition of $A \cup B$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-partition

I am having trouble with this question. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by $A\oplus B$? Does it mean $(A - B)\cup(B - A)$?

Comment: @APCorreia it is the exclusive or symbol. Meaning A or B, but not both.

Comment: HINT: Every member of $A\cup B$ belongs to exactly one of $A$ and $B$ or to both $A$ and $B$. What is the set of members of $A\cup B$ that belong to exactly one of $A$ and $B$? To both $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @SirStat In Set Theory it's not called "exclusive or", it's called symmetric difference and usually denoted by $\Delta$.

Comment: @SirStat Why did you change the title?
If you have another question, ASK ANOTHER QUESTION. Don't change an already answered question for another one.

Answer (score 2):

If $B = \emptyset$ and $A\ne\emptyset$ then $\{A\oplus B, A\cap B\} = \{A,\emptyset\}$ is NOT a partition of $A\cup B =A$

Comment: @APCorreia Formally, a partition of a set *cannot* contain the empty set. Thus, the example in this answer is a correct counter example to the given question.